# Sublime Text strange behaviour

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a strange behaviour on my Sublime3 editor. I just started using it, having not much experience with.

I add some code like

```
use Kakuki\Reports\Models\Campaign;
```

And on save the code is kicked out. 
Apparently it seems that PHPTools package caused this issue. How do I configure this Package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling PSR mode via the User Preferences.

1. From the "Preferences" menu, choose "Package Settings", "PHPTools" and then "Settings - User".
2. Paste `{ "psr":"False" }` into that file. (If that file is not already empty, just add `, "psr" : "False"` to the last line in that file. )
3. Save the preferences file and create a new "New View Into File".

Any time you install a new Sublime Text package, it's a good idea to take a look at its configurable options. You can do this from the "Preferences" menu, and then "Package Settings", the name of your package and finally "Settings - Default". Most package developers will pre-populate this file with all of the available options and comments about what they do. Note that you shouldn't edit this file (it will be overwritten every time the package updates), but you can use this to inform your user settings as above.